# Unit test a single processor implementation (java) in Kafka Streams?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka-streams

The specific problem encountered is mocking context, state stores, and window objects pass into the function process.

Looks like all the examples, e.g., [here](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-streams-unit-testing) and [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/common/blob/235cd03465b1cde872a4d0a95831beabf05e444d/utility-belt/src/test/java/io/confluent/admin/utils/ClusterStatusSASLTest.java) are unit tests at the stream level (e.g., mockStreams, or using EmbeddedKafkaCluster).

Comment: btw may I suggest Spock for testing in Java (we’ll, Groovy really). It makes mocking really easy and pleasant. So easy you may go overboard :)

Comment: Kafka 1.1 (will be release shortly) add public test artifacts that you can use for unit testing. Check out KIP-247 for details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-247%3A+Add+public+test+utils+for+Kafka+Streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to test a single processor implementation, and need to mock context, state stores, etc, I would just use whatever testing tools you ordinarily use to mock things (Mockito, CGLIB, etc).

Beyond the scope of your question, there is also the [ProcessorTopologyTestDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45517649/741970). Posting in case you missed it. Kafka Streams is getting new/improved testing functionality in an [upcoming version](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-247%3A+Add+public+test+utils+for+Kafka+Streams).