# Kafka stream api - how to test processing with embedded kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'd like to test my processor with embedded kafka. Is it even possible?

When I run the app locally with Kafka & ZK then it works perfectly - my example listener receives the message same as processor (great, both listen to the same topic), but when I test it with embedded kafka then only method annotated with `@KafkaListener` gets the message but processor doesn't get anything.

I would like to send message to the processor's topic, then check if it sent the result to the other topic.

Is there any solution for such usecase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test Kafka Streams topology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825753/test-kafka-streams-topology)

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to test your code using `TopologyTestDriver`: https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html

You can also use `KafkaEmbedded`, or maybe better `EmbeddedKafkaCluster`. For examples, check out the Kafka Streams integration tests: https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration