# KafkaStreams How to instantiate a ConsumerRecordFactory?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, inferred-type

I am trying to use the `ConsumerRecordFactory` provided by Kafka Streams following mainly the [confluent doc](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/test-streams.html) to test a streaming application, here is the code I have so far:

```
// Properties of the application
Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();

// Give the Streams application a unique name.  The name must be unique in the Kafka cluster
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "testing_application");
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummyserver:2181");

// Create the topology builder
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

// Run it on the test driver
TopologyTestDriver testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);

// Feed input data
ConsumerRecordFactory<String, Integer> factory = new ConsumerRecordFactory<>(
        "input-topic",
        new StringSerializer(),
        new IntegerSerializer()
);

// Create a test record
ConsumerRecordFactory<byte[], byte[]> record = factory.create("key", 42L);
```

My problem is that when I compile my code I get the following error:

```
Error:(70, 52) java: reference to create is ambiguous
  both method create(K,V,long) in org.apache.kafka.streams.test.ConsumerRecordFactory
  and method create(java.lang.String,V,long) in org.apache.kafka.streams.test.ConsumerRecordFactory match
```

So I understand that kafka streams defines the generic method `create(K,V,long)` and that when I create my factory with non generic types I create a new method which is in conflict with the first one.

My question is how am I supposed to instanciate my `ConsumerRecordFactory`?

I tried making my factory more generic with `ConsumerRecordFactory<Object, Integer>` but then the inferred type doesn't match. And I can't find other example the confluent github repo [kafka-streams-examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples) doesn't seem to use a `ConsumerRecordFactory`, and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45517649/4194289) seems to be using the same code as the documentation.

(I am aware that the problem is more about java than about kafka streams but I thought that tagging it with `apache-kafka-streams` is a good way to reach people used to the `ConsumerRecordFactory`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in the below code:

```
// Feed input data ConsumerRecordFactory<String, Integer> factory = new ConsumerRecordFactory<>(
        "input-topic",
        new StringSerializer(),
        new IntegerSerializer() );

// Create a test record
ConsumerRecordFactory<byte[], byte[]> record = factory.create("key", 42L);
```

1. You have defined valueType as **Integer** in the `ConsumerRecordFactory`, but in `create()` method you are passing **Long** type value.
2. `factory.create()` returns a `ConsumerRecord` instead of `ConsumerRecordFactory`.

Regarding the ambiguity of method, you are right. So avoid that issue, use following :

```
ConsumerRecordFactory<String, Integer> factory = new ConsumerRecordFactory<>( 
        new StringSerializer(),
        new IntegerSerializer()
);
// Use ConsumerRecord here instead of ConsumerRecordFactory
ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record = factory.create("input-topic","key", 42);
```

Comment: You're right about the types error, it was a bad copy past but is not my actual code. About your solution the the factory it seems to be working, but I don't understand why not defining the topic name in the factory but rather in the record solves the problem?

Comment: Great. This ambiguity will occur when your <K> is String. But if you define some other key type, it will work as the method signature will be unique. You can find more details here : https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/test/ConsumerRecordFactory.html,

Comment: If you think it solves your issue, feel free to accept/upvote the answer :)

Comment: Yup I was just reading the doc and testing a bit more before accepting :)